# Local SQLite connection on JDeveloper

Tags: sqlite, mobile, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm completely new to ADF Mobile and have previously made a connection to and SQLite DB with NetBeans. I'm replicating the code, and I'm getting an *Import java.sql.DriverManager not found* error (in bold).

package mobile;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
**import java.sql.DriverManager;**
import java.sql.*;

public class Connect {
public Connect() {
    super();
}


public class JavaConnect {

    static Connection conn = null;
    static ResultSet rs = null;
    static PreparedStatement pst = null;

    public static Connection DBConnect() {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:AlternativeIdentification.sqlite");
            System.out.println("Connection established");
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: did you import the library with the jar in your application?

Comment: Yeah I did. I ended up getting this to work like 5 minutes ago with a completely different method, but it's really puzzling me as to why this did not work. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Wait hold on. Which jar file was I meant to import?

Comment: No problem but you should do a google search for this, I know only that what you are getting is coming from this. Can you explain how did you import the jar? the steps please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/. Then in your JDeveloper go to Tools>ManageLibraries and create a new library. Check the 'DeployedByDefault' checkbox there and add the JAR in the library (>addEntry). Then go to your Project, go to ProjectProperties and then to Libraries and Classpath and click on Add Library to add your new library to your project. Rebuild your project or restart JDeveloper in the worst case and you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your previous message in time. I had some other JAR file installed (I needed it in NetBeans for the connection).

What you said works! My word, I've been Googling like mad for this for the past week. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Can I ask: why is this necessary for JDev but not NetBeans?

Comment: @Ari Anastassiou You're welcome. Maybe in NetBeans this jar is added by default. I do not know for sure. Tung!

Comment: I think I added it manually last time as well. My memory is returning haha :D - such an amateur mistake. Thanks again! :)